# What is the meaning of a single-point constraint on the $L^p$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

An element of $L^1[0,1]$ is defined as the equivalence class of functions which are equal a.e.

Let $A$ be the subset of $L^1[0,1]$ such that $f\in A$ if and only if $f(0)=0$. Then clearly $A=L^1[0,1]$.

Now, let $B$ be the subset of $L^1[0,1]$ such that $f\in B$ if and only if $f(0)=1$. Again, $B=L^1[0,1]$.

But if we consider $A\cap B$, there does not exist a function $f$ such that $f(0)=0=1$. Is $A\cap B$ still equal to the entire set $L^1[0,1]$?

The answer seems to be "Yes" since it is still a constraint an a single point, $1$. But it also seems to be "No" because no element of $L^1[0,1]$ can satisfy $0=1$.

I must be missing something here but I can't figure out what. I would also appreciate any references that I could look up. Thank you.

Comment: Your sets are not even defined . $f(0)$ is not a well defined number for a function $f$ in $L^{1}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, I'm confused. Are you saying that only integrals are well defined numbers for a function $f$ in $L^1$?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$. This means that for a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, if we let $g = f + c1_{\{0\}}$ then $g = f$ almost everywhere. This means that $f$ and $g$ represent the same element of $L^1[0,1]$ but $f(0) \neq g(0)$.